# Generate background_gradient per group

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame([['A', 1], ['A', 3], ['B', 7], ['B', 4]])
```

How can I use a [`Styler`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.formats.style.Styler.html) to print it with a [background gradient](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient.html#pandas.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient) by rank within each [group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) when grouping by the first column? I know how to get the rank by group:

```
df.groupby(0).rank()
```

And I can apply a background gradient to the data like this:

```
df.style.background_gradient()
```

But how can I make the background gradient work according to the group rank? I can apply the gradient to the data like this:

```
df.style.background_gradient()
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

As you see, the gradient is applied by rank in the entire column `1`, instead of separately for each group. I can also apply the style to the grouped rank:

```
df.groupby(0).rank().style.background_gradient()
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

The question is, how can I have the output above have the same colors as the output below?

Comment: it's not clear what are you after... Do you want to highlight the whole rows?

Comment: No, each cell is enough. I made the example too simple, in practice I am grouping by an index column, so I only have a single data-column.

Comment: `df.groupby(0).rank().style.background_gradient()`?

Comment: That doesn't work, because then the numbers are the rank instead of the actual data.

Comment: So which column would you like to highlight?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what I have now, does that make it clearer?

Comment: @BjörnPollex did you find out how to do it?

Comment: @Tonja No I did not. Haven't come back to it in a while.